# JavaScript format date like in PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing, date

I need to parse date from JSON (I can't do any change in this JSON on server).

```
{ ...
"time":"2014-02-14 18:37:48",
...
}
```

In [php date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) it is: YYYY-mm-dd HH:ii:ss

I want to change date format, for example to "dd.mm.YYYY HH:ii". In PHP it is easy, but in JavaScript I do not know how to parse it.

I try [jQuery dateFormat](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat), but I still do an error :-(

Can you please help me?

Comment: Check out [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) or [phpjs's `date()` function](http://phpjs.org/functions/date/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr=time.split(' ');

var date_arr=arr[0];

var time_arr=arr[1];

var temp_date=date_arr.split('-');
var temp_time=time_arr.split(':');

var js_date=temp_date[2]+'.'+temp_date[1]+'.'+temp_date[0]+' '+temp_time[0]+":"+temp_time[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do all by your hands. Javascript's Date object has enough methods.
So please try smth like this:

```
var dateTime = new Date(Date.parse("2014-02-14 18:37:48"));
var date = dateTime.getDate().toString().length > 1 ? dateTime.getDate() : '0' + dateTime.getDate();
var month = dateTime.getMonth().toString().length > 1 ? dateTime.getMonth() + 1 : '0' + (dateTime.getMonth() + 1);
var hours = dateTime.getHours().toString().length > 1 ? dateTime.getHours() : '0' + dateTime.getHours();
var minutes = dateTime.getMinutes().toString().length > 1 ? dateTime.getMinutes() : '0' + dateTime.getMinutes();

var formattedDate = date + '.' + month + '.' + dateTime.getFullYear() + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes;
console.log(formattedDate);
```